# R: Select earliest date for each ID and step in a process except when steps appear out of order

Tags: r, dplyr

The goal is for each UniqueID, to select the earliest Date that occurs in the data frame for each Step. This can be done by creating a data frame for each Step, sorting by UniqueID and dates oldest to newest, and then removing duplicated UniqueID.

The difficult part is that each Step represents steps in a process which must occur in order. Step 2 can never occur before Step 1 and so on, and if records show that Step 2 has occurred before step 1, then those records indicate errors in the data that should be ignored.

So in the example data frame below, for UniqueIDs of "A" we would ignore the earliest two instances of Step 2 because they occur before the earliest incidence of Step 1 which is not permitted. We can then proceed to obtain the earliest instance of each step that does occur in the permitted order to get the desired result of:

```
 Step 1 = 9/07/2015  
 Step 2 = 20/07/2015  
 Step 3 = 24/07/2015
```

For UniqueIDs of "B", the earliest instance of Step 3 occurs before the earliest instance of Step 2 so it must be ignored. Once we ignore this we can go on to obtain the following desired values:

```
 Step 1 = 1/06/2015  
 Step 2 = 22/06/2015  
 Step 3 = 8/07/2015
```

Example dataframe:

```
 UniqueID   Date Step
    A  3/07/2015    2
    A  7/07/2015    2
    A  9/07/2015    1
    A 14/07/2015    1
    A 17/07/2015    1
    A 20/07/2015    2
    A 23/07/2015    2
    A 24/07/2015    3
    A 29/07/2015    3
    B  1/06/2015    1
    B 15/06/2015    1
    B 22/06/2015    1
    B 29/06/2015    1
    B 13/07/2015    3
    B 22/06/2015    2
    B  8/07/2015    3
    B 27/07/2015    3
```

The real data set is very large. What techniques might we be able to use to efficiently attain the desired output. We would like a data frame with a row for each UniqueID and a column for each Step showing the date that each ID reached each Step.

Here is the dput for my example data frame:

```
structure(list(UniqueID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(16619, 16623, 16625, 
16630, 16633, 16636, 16639, 16640, 16645, 16587, 16601, 16608, 
16615, 16629, 16608, 16624, 16643), class = "Date"), Step = c(2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2)), .Names = c("UniqueID", 
"Date", "Step"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(UniqueID, Step) %>% filter(Date==min(Date)) %>% arrange(Step)` assuming $df$Date$ is of the right format.

Comment: @Khashaa you havn't read the question obviously...

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right:)

Comment: @Khashaa thanks though. That's a better way to do what I was doing to with filter to get the earliest date for each step.

Comment: Now I've read the question carefully, I think you can filter out the erratic entries as `df %>%  group_by(UniqueID) %>%  mutate(id=rleid(Step)) %>% filter(Step<=id)`. Haven't checked the general validity, so I hastily post it as a comment. (rleid is from `data.table`)

Comment: @Khashaa that's brilliant. I was also playing around with `rleid` but haven't think of the `filter(Step<=id)` part. Adding just `group_by(UniqueID, Step) %>% filter(Date==min(Date))` to the end and you have a very nice solution

Comment: Some combination of `diff(Step)>=0` might be better.

Comment: @Khashaa I though about it too, but it won't work if you have two consecutive out of order values. Because lets say you have 2 then 4 then 3. So 4-3>=0

Comment: So, it boils down to `longest nondecreasing subsequence` problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a quick function that could check the correctness of the order of steps.
Here is one suggestion:

```
df <- group_by(df,UniqueID) %>%
           mutate(position1=sapply(Step,function(y) if(y==1){0} else{
                                     min(which(Step<y))
                                       }
            ),
            position2=1:length(Step)) %>%
            print
df <- filter(df,position1<=position2) %>%
                       select(-position1,-position2)
```

First it creates 2 extra columns: position1 defines the minimal position of an element that is less then current step. Position2 is just an alias for a position of this step in current group. Obviously, if position1 is greater than position2, the step is "incorrect": for example, if step2 goes before step1.
After filtering, you will have data frame with all correct steps, and than you can just use Khashaa's method.

Comment: This works, but only for the observations with UniqueID of A. How can we modify the functions so that they run separately for each instances of UniqueID, as though they were a separate table?

Comment: the first group_by statement group_by(df,UniqueID) should do just that

Comment: Thanks this works but with one modification. I changed this line:
  
`min(which(Step<y))`  

To this:

`min(which(Step==y-1))`

This will detect the minimal position of an element that is exactly one step less than the current step.

Comment: Also this worked for the example dataset, but using the real dataset with 2000 UniqueID and 5000 records it crashes. The UniqueID is as a factor. Could it help to change the data type?

Comment: It is more likely that the real dataset has some entries that couldn't be processed by this function, for example, when one value is NA or when there is just one value. Could you send an example of the data with the UniqueID that causes it to fail?